# How to tells disks apart during install?

Tags: server

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 16.04.2 on virtualbox, but i cant tell my disks apart. I have 3 25GB disks and 1 16GB disk, all in VDI format. I would like to install GRUB on the 16GB disk (Where the OS is installed) but i cant figure out which disk is which. Is there a simple way to figure this out without restarting the installation?

Comment: How are you installing? If via 'Try Ubuntu', you can open a terminal window and run the following commands, that help you identify the virtual disks: `df` , `sudo lsblk -f` , `sudo lsblk -m` , `sudo parted -ls`. If you are installing directly via 'Install Ubuntu', it is probably more difficult, which means 'I don't know'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run terminal commands by switching to a different virtual console with Alt+F2 (or +F3, +F4, etc.) The command `blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda` will show you the size in bytes of the device /dev/sda. If you want more info, `fdisk -l /dev/sda` will also show you a partition layout. Once you're done, Alt+F1 should put you back in the installer.